# How to escape percent (%) when using parameters in a FOR loop?

Tags: batch-file

The usual escape character in dos batch files is caret, `^`. However for percent, `%`,  the delimiter for variables, the escape is to double up the percents: `%%cd%%`.  Things change when using [parameter extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) inside a `for` loop. Instead of `%%~dpnx0` emitting `%~dpnx0`, as it will outside the loop, it carries out the substitution, emitting `D:\Scripts\foo.py`.

Here's a batch file demonstration:

```
@echo off
echo This is a pipe: ^|
echo Use this var for the current directory: %%cd%%
echo Use this to echo full path of running batch file: %%~dpnx0

for %%a in (foo.py baz.py) do (
  echo @python %%~dpnxa ^> %%~na.bat
  )
```

These are the results I get:

```
This is a pipe: |
Use this var for the current directory: %cd%
Use this to echo full path of running batch file: %~dpnx0
@python d:\Scripts\foo.py > foo.bat
@python d:\Scripts\baz.py > baz.bat
```

But this is what I want:

```
This is a pipe: |
Use this var for the current directory: %cd%
Use this to echo full path of running batch file: %~dpnx0
@python %~dpnxa > foo.bat
@python %~dpnxa > baz.bat
```

I've tried doubling, tripling, and quadrupling the percents as well is interspersing carets throughout, all without success.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is impossible to prevent a FOR variable expression from expanding. If a FOR is in effect with variable X defined, then the FOR expansion phase will always expand `%X`.

But you can hide the percent behind another FOR variable :)

The following gives the result you are looking for:

```
@echo off
echo This is a pipe: ^|
echo Use this var for the current directory: %%cd%%
echo Use this to echo full path of running batch file: %%~dpnx0

for %%P in (%%) do for %%A in (foo.py baz.py) do (
  echo @python %%P~dpnxA ^> %%~nA.bat
)
```

FOR variables have global scope (though they are only accessible within the DO clause). This can lead to an insidious problem. Any time you have a subroutine that uses a percent literal within a FOR loop, then you are at risk of unintended results! A FOR statement issued before your CALL can influence the results of a FOR DO clause within your CALLed routine.

```
@echo off
for %%) in (Yikes!) do call :test
exit /b

:test
echo This works outside loop (confidence = 100%%)
for %%A in (1) do echo This does not work inside loop (confidence = 100%%)
for %%P in (%%) do for %%A in (1) do echo This works inside loop (confidence = 100%%P)
exit /b
```

Here is the output

```
This works outside loop (confidence = 100%)
This does not work inside loop (confidence = 100Yikes
This works inside loop (confidence = 100%)
```

Comment: whoa, that is weird, but it works, +1. Thanks! (delaying an Accept for a bit to see if any other solutions come forward)

Comment: @mattwilkie - I've added another example demonstrating how insidious the problem can be!

Answer (score 5):

You could use delayed expansion or call-percent expansion, or like dbenham shows expanding another FOR variable.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set percent=%%
set "line=%%~dpnxa ^>"
for %%a in (foo.py baz.py) do (
  echo @python !percent!~dpnxa ^> %%~na.bat
  call echo @python %%line%% %%~nxa.bat
)
```